# Declare class member at runtime in D

Tags: templates, class, struct, d

I want the following struct as a class member, but I don't know the type of `T`, so I need "declare" the struct at runtime.

```
struct Chunk (T) {
    string id;
    T[][] data;
}

class FileBla {
    this() {
        Chunk !int ck; // need to be turned in a class member
    }
}
```

Should be missing something easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *template* the class as well:

```
import std.stdio;

struct Chunk (T) {
    string id;
    T[][] data;
}

class FileBla(T) {
private:
    Chunk!T ck;
}

void main() {
    auto f = new FileBla!int;
    writeln(typeid(f.ck));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you're used to programming in dynamic languages and are now trying to learn a static language.

There are at least three reasonable ways to do this:

Template FileBla, too:

```
class FileBla(T) {
    Chunk!T ck;

    // Other stuff.
}
```

Wrap Chunk in a polymorphic class.

Allocate Chunk on the heap and store a `void*` pointer to it.  This is the old C-style way to do things, will require manually casting the pointer to the correct type, and is not memory safe.  Nonetheless it is occasionally useful.